# How ActivityRecognition works?

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am eager to know how ActivityRecognition which is in GooglePlay Services works?

- I think activities are recognized by accelerometer data.Is it right?.Please give me the details how it goes?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this answer also and your post was one of the top results on Google. I did a little more digging and found this https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi.html which says:

> The activities are detected by periodically waking up the device and reading short bursts of sensor data. It only makes use of low power sensors in order to keep the power usage to a minimum. For example, it can detect if the user is currently on foot, in a car, on a bicycle or still.

It doesn't explicitly say which sensors it uses, but we can safely assume that accelerometer is one of them. Since it says sensors (plural) it evidently uses others. But since it says low power you don't have to worry about it using GPS or anything like that. However, it does say that it wakes the device up which would bring it out of its super power saving mode. So, even though it is low power you still may not want it running every 5 seconds all day long. The documentation further down says:

> A common use case is that an application wants to monitor activities in the background and perform an action when a specific activity is detected. To do this without needing a service that is always on in the background consuming resources, detected activities are delivered via an intent. The application specifies a PendingIntent callback (typically an IntentService) which will be called when activities are detected. See the documentation of PendingIntent for more details.